# Is there any specification saying what is still considered as valid JSONP?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I need to parse JSONP messages in .NET and find JSON in those messages. Is there any up to date specification describing a valid JSONP message?

I found [this blog post](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) (from 2005) by Bob Ippolito specifying the first JSONP proposal, where a JSONP message could contain almost any JavaScript code.

I also found a probably [more recent specification](http://www.json-p.org/) on json-p.org allowing only function calls to functions specified in a requesting URI parameter named `callback`.

Finally [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) says:

> While the padding (prefix) is typically the name of a callback
>   function that is defined within the execution context of the browser,
>   it may also be a variable assignment, an if statement, or any other
>   JavaScript statement. The response to a JSONP request (namely, a
>   request following the JSONP usage pattern) is not JSON and is not
>   parsed as JSON; the returned payload can be any arbitrary JavaScript
>   expression, and it does not need to include any JSON at all. But
>   conventionally, it is a JavaScript fragment that invokes a function
>   call on some JSON-formatted data.

So is there any global definition what makes a valid JSONP response and what JavaScript constructs are allowed? Should I expect any JavaScript code, because that is what current browsers accept (because it has `application/javascript` content type)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JSONP is a pattern rather than a language (as is the case with JSON), there is no standard.

It's name implies that you'll get a valid JSON object wrapped in a function call.

Indeed, the "specification" which tells you what will be included in the response should be something for the [API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) [you're subscribing to](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/json.html) [to document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Answer (score 2):

It could literally be any valid JavaScript because what it does is append a new script tag to the page. The reason you see `callback({...JSON...})` is because it's invoking the callback function you passed into the URL of the script tag. However, you could put an entire web application's worth of function calls and other things in the same payload.

You ought to look into Cross-Origin Resource Sharing as an alternative to JSONP. It allows regular AJAX to talk directly across origins using the addition of a few HTTP headers. It's a great alternative to JSONP which is stuck with the limitations of a GET request (2083 character URL limit in most, if not all, versions of IE).